# How divide two variables in bash script / How perform Sine function on a variable?

Tags: bash

I am very new to bash and scripting. I am trying to extract some numbers from a file, then divide these numbers or performing Sine function on them, and then put them in a new variable. I must say that my numbers are not integers they are floating points.

For example, I have these two lines:

```
T_refl=$(awk '/diff_data/ { print $2 }' *.txt)
U_refl=$(awk '/refl_data/ { print $2 }' *.txt)
```

Then I want to do some operations and put the value in the following variables:

```
Reduc=$(T_refl/U_refl) 
Resol=$(T_refl/2*sin(U_refl))
```

I tried different things like `awk`, `expr`, `bc`, and `let` but I simply can not do this step and I got different types of errors. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: I would write this in `bc`, because this language can do float arithmetic and also calculate the sine. The code you posted does not do any calculation. It just tries to execute the program `T_refl/U_refl`. `awk` would should also be an option, but I don't know how reliable the floating point calculation is in awk. `let` and `expr` obviously can't be used.

Answer (score 1):

The shell only supports integer arithmetic, so you can't do it directly with it.

Since you're already using `awk` then you could do all the processing in a single call:

```bash
awk '
    /diff_data/ { T_refl = $2 }
    /refl_data/ { U_refl = $2 }
    END {
        Reduc = T_refl / U_refl
        Resol = T_refl / 2*sin(U_refl)
        print T_refl, U_refl, Reduc, Resol
    }
' file.txt
```